# Nested Modal Popups React or any other

Tags: reactjs

Need modal inside modal if you click on edit then is one modal is opening. I need one more modal inside that opened modal

Answer (score 0):

To create nested modal popups in React you can use a combination of modal components and conditional rendering.

Example

```
import React from 'react';

const ParentModal = () => {
  const [showChildModal, setShowChildModal] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShowChildModal(true)}>Show Child Modal</button>
      {showChildModal && <ChildModal onClose={() => setShowChildModal(false)} />}
    </>
  );
};

const ChildModal = ({ onClose }) => {
  const [showGrandchildModal, setShowGrandchildModal] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShowGrandchildModal(true)}>Show Grandchild Modal</button>
      {showGrandchildModal && <GrandchildModal onClose={() => setShowGrandchildModal(false)} />}
      <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
    </>
  );
};

const GrandchildModal = ({ onClose }) => (
  <>
    <p>I'm the grandchild modal!</p>
    <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
  </>
);

export default ParentModal;
```

In the above example, we have three modal components: ParentModal, ChildModal, and GrandchildModal. The ParentModal component is the root of the nested modal popups, and it contains a button that will show the ChildModal when clicked. The ChildModal component, in turn, contains a button that will show the GrandchildModal when clicked. Each modal component also has a "Close" button that will close the modal when clicked.

We use the useState hook in each component to track the state of the modal (whether it is open or closed), and we use conditional rendering

Comment: It is not possible with React bootstrap 5.0 (I need if we can open modal with html css or javascript) The above example closes one popup and enables another popup. We need nested one, N number of popups can be opened on screen .